# Create Master detail with Entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have a blogPost that should take the category name and to do this I've done like this in get action :

```
public ActionResult Add()
        {
            ViewBag.CategoryList = new SelectList(_categoryRepository.GetAllCategory(), "Id", "Name");
            return View(new BlogPost());

        }
```

and in the View I have :

```
@model Blog.Domain.Model.BlogPost
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AddPost";
    Layout = "~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
}

<fieldset>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Blog", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary()
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(b => b.Title)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(b => b.Title)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(b => b.Title)
        </div>

        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(b => b.Body)
            @Html.EditorFor(b => b.Body)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(b => b.Body)
        </div>

        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(b => b.Summary)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(b => b.Summary)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(b => b.Summary)
        </div>

        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(b => b.Category)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Category.Id, ViewBag.CategoryList as SelectList, "--- Select Category ---", new { @class = "some_class" })
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Add Post" />
        </div>
    }
</fieldset>
```

and in the Post action I have write this code :

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Add(BlogPost blogPost)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                blogPost.PublishDate = DateTime.Now;
                _blogPostRepository.AddPost(blogPost);
                _blogPostRepository.Save();
                return View();
            }
            return View();
        }
```

I'm not sure that I have written this code exactly correct or not , but I have this trouble for a lone time ! master detail inserting with entity framework actually in this case selecting a category and sending it to database successfully , if you have write something like this before please help me about that, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're setting up two drop down lists and assigning the value of one to the model's ID field, which I assume is the ID of the blog post entity..?

1. Remove the @Html.DropDownList(...) statement
2. Modify the first parameter of @Html.DropDownListFor(...) to a lambda expression selecting the CategoryId property of the model/entity (whatever the FK field name is for Category, presumably model => model.CategoryId)

   @Html.LabelFor(b => b.Category)
       @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryId, ViewBag.CategoryList as SelectList, "--- Select Category ---", new { @class = "some_class" })

Comment: really sorry about my mistake( two drop down list), I just copy and past and didn't notice about the first one that was a comment! I'm really mixed up , I tried what you said but now I got this error :There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Category.Id'.